# Apache generating huge "AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" error log

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu).

The problems is [client 110.191.197.24:50666] visit **/var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w** generating huge error logs.Could anyone please help me find out what cause these logs?

apache error.log

```
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:51.623953 2014] [core:error] [pid 26122] [client 110.191.180.11:50296] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:52.399540 2014] [core:error] [pid 26097] [client 110.191.180.244:50666] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:52.832698 2014] [core:error] [pid 26006] [client 110.191.197.68:49746] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:53.605543 2014] [core:error] [pid 26270] [client 110.191.180.152:50129] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:53.707244 2014] [core:error] [pid 26043] [client 110.191.181.148:51824] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:54.444643 2014] [core:error] [pid 26180] [client 110.191.195.101:51994] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
[Thu Dec 25 11:27:56.196567 2014] [core:error] [pid 26287] [client 110.191.194.177:50968] AH00126: Invalid URI in request X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

apache access.log

```
IP:80 110.191.196.78 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:28 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
115.28.87.83:80 110.191.195.207 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:29 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
115.28.87.83:80 110.191.195.103 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:29 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
115.28.87.83:80 110.191.196.140 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:31 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
localhost:80 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:31 +0800] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
115.28.87.83:80 110.191.195.227 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:32 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
115.28.87.83:80 110.191.180.138 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:32 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
localhost:80 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:33 +0800] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
myserverIP:80 110.191.181.99 - - [25/Dec/2014:11:28:34 +0800] "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 400 226 "-" "-"
```

virtulhost error.log

```
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:37.791909 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 24030] [client 110.191.195.251:49302] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=AA7C5A5DC83B437182D5A43B83F7F3DE
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:40.399250 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23989] [client 110.191.194.66:65106] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=10DEFE0BE649453DAD853253C92646A9
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:42.493238 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23964] [client 110.191.178.205:49927] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=96061DA3AB6E430F9E2634D61FACEE7D
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:43.511376 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23942] [client 110.191.178.240:50707] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=50A4D3C123D7457DAB5C1D2C4E8592AD
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:45.609891 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23968] [client 110.191.195.57:50955] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=BDF60CBE2A43475DBB30D0D503A49ACB
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:46.796242 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23969] [client 110.191.197.77:49871] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=F5D70438F0D94285918055B96C17C48E
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:47.513423 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23952] [client 110.191.179.101:60409] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=D0EC0AE349E54CC393D4B4613547CA57
[Thu Dec 25 10:42:47.974533 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 23943] [client 110.191.197.24:50666] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prokfv2/chatapp/www/w, referer: http://www.4gfy.com/syzbs.html?no_cache=31583060C9184AF09E1211A9CB1BA67F
```